# Error 'UnAuthorized' when using the "GET" requests for Twiiter API 1.1 in C#

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, httpwebrequest, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to connect to twitter api from my c# application using the "GET" requests. I read the following article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/247336/Twitter-OAuth-authentication-using-Net
Which works great with me and I'm able to post a tweet successfully. But When I try to use it with "GET" and the Twitter API 1.1, it keeps giving me the error 'UnAuthorized'

This is my code:

```
 var oauth_token = "";
        var oauth_token_secret = "";
        var oauth_consumer_key = "";
        var oauth_consumer_secret = "";

        // oauth implementation details
        var oauth_version = "1.0";
        var oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";

        // unique request details
        var oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(
            new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
        var timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow
            - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();

        // message api details
        var Id = "111111111111111";// the ID of the tweet need to get info about it
        var resource_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json";
        // create oauth signature
        var baseFormat = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" +
                        "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&status={6}";

        var baseString = string.Format(baseFormat,
                                    oauth_consumer_key,
                                    oauth_nonce,
                                    oauth_signature_method,
                                    oauth_timestamp,
                                    oauth_token,
                                    oauth_version,
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(status)
                                    );

        baseString = string.Concat("POST&", Uri.EscapeDataString(resource_url), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString));

        var compositeKey = string.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_secret),
                                "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret));

        string oauth_signature;
        using (HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey)))
        {
            oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(
                hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)));
        }

        // create the request header
        var headerFormat = "OAuth oauth_nonce=\"{0}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{1}\", " +
                           "oauth_timestamp=\"{2}\", oauth_consumer_key=\"{3}\", " +
                           "oauth_token=\"{4}\", oauth_signature=\"{5}\", " +
                           "oauth_version=\"{6}\"";

        var authHeader = string.Format(headerFormat,
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version)
                        );

        Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resource_url + "?id=" + Id);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
        request.Method = "GET";// "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader s = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encode);
        string test = s.ReadLine();
```

Can you help me of how to edit it to be working with "GET"?

Thank you,